# Dynamic Milestone Trend Analysis Graph needs same y-axis as x-axis in Excel with VBA

Tags: excel, graph, excel-2013, vba

After a couple hours of work I come to you guys with this graphing problem. I need to create a Milestone-Trend-Analysis which can be seen on the [german wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meilensteintrendanalyse) , though not in the english version.

**General Information**

In short, the diagram has report dates on the x-axis (for now, on every first of the month, another report is due).
The y-axis should mirror the x-axis completely. In length and also the tickmarks. The dates get bigger from the bottom to the top.
In my case the x-Axis is on top of the diagram.

Every report consists of a number of "due-dates", one for each assignement in progress. They are the estimated "finishing dates" of that particular assignement.

If the estimated finishing date stays the same in the next report period, the graph for that assignement stays on the same level. If the estimate is earlier, the graph trends down. Normally they go up, since the assignement has some delay :-D

The x-axis needs to be dynamic, since the whole project is basically finished when its last assignement is finished. If one of the assignements is running late, the whole project gets delayed an thus the x-axis needs to be longer/get more ticks.
Since the y-Axis mirrors that, it has to change too.

**MY PROBLEM**

The x-axis has a number of discreet values, since the reports come in every month, or every two weeks. But that does not change.
The values for the finishing dates are continuous, since the assignements can be terminated whenever.

That leaves me with the problem of having to cut the y-axis in equal-size chunks, although the months of the year are not equal in size. At least that is, what I think excel forces me to do.

I can assign a max limit and a min limit for the y-axis and I can assign a distance between each main tickmark. Since Excel works with a continous number for each date, the 2014/01/01 would be 41640. And 2015/01/01 is 42005. Since I have 12 month on the x-axis and I need 12 on the y axis, I would have to have the main Ticks at a distance of 30.42 ... which gives me the following Months on my axis

January January March .... December December

Does anyone know an answer for this? Is there a way to have excel make the tickmarks on the y-axis not equal distance?

Any input greatly appreciated.

Kaz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find a way to make Excel have variable tick mark distances. But since I coud not have it that way, I had to make the month equally long.

This works for me now:

```
'calculate the norm for different type of month including Schaltjahr
Select Case cellMonth

        'February
    Case 2

        'Schaltjahr and Schaltjahrhundert
        If (cellYear Mod 4 = 0) Or (cellYear Mod 400 = 0) Then

            resultDay = (30 / 29) * cellDay

        Else

            resultDay = (30 / 28) * cellDay
        End If

        '31 day months
    Case 1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12

        resultDay = (30 / 31) * cellDay

        '30 day months
    Case Else

        resultDay = cellDay

End Select
```

Now I just have to scale the axis to `numberOfMonths * 30`. It now leaves adjusting the names of the y-Axis, which seems to be a whole different story.

Kaz

Answer (score 0):

You can put arbitrary labels along the Y axis by adding a dummy XY series.

Here is some data that I think captures your issue, plus a line chart showing the data, plus the data that I'll use to construct a dummy Y axis.

I used a line chart so the X axis at least would be easy. You just have to make sure that the axis is formatted as a date axis with Base Unit of Days.

[image: Data and starting chart]

Here is how I built the axis.

**Top Left Chart Below:** I copied the dummy axis data, both columns of the data includingt the header row. I selected the chart, and used Paste Special to add the data as a new series, data in columns, series names in first row, categories in first column (but don't replace existing categories).

**Top Right Chart Below:** I right-clicked on the added series, clicked on Change Series Chart Type, and selected XY Scatter with Lines and Markers. Excel also put this series onto the secondary axes.

**Middle Left Chart Below:** I formatted the added series to be plotted on the Primary axis.

**Middle Right Chart Below:** I changed the scale of the vertical axis, giving it a minimum of the first date and a maximum of the last (1/1/16 to 9/1/16).

**Bottom Left Chart Below:** I formatted the vertical axis to show no labels.

**Bottom Right Chart Below:** Format format format. I formatted the dummy axis series so it used light gary lines (matching the horizontal axis) and light gray cross markers (simulating tickmarks). I changed the tickmarks of the horizontal axis so they crossed the axis, matching the cross markers of the dummy series. I added data labels to the left of the dummy series points, simulating vertical axis labels.

[image]